# Can authenticate through Negotiate with PowerShell but not with Java

Tags: kerberos, java

I need some help setting up Kerberos on SharePoint correctly for a test single farm server.

I am able to successfully use PowerShell to authenticate to this server as a given kerberos user:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://win-qbfsb933r5p -UseDefaultCredentials
Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://win-qbfsb933r5p -Credential "winlab\kerberos"
```

But when I try to authenticate to SharePoint with Java using [using this approach](http://www.chrisweldon.net/sharepoint/sharepoint-rest-api-authentication-from-java/) I always get a 401 error no matter what I do.

However, I am able to connect java to other non-SharePoint IIS web sites fine. I can create a simple IIS application pool on port 81 on the same IIS host also protected by Negotiate, and I can use this same java program to authenticate. *It is just SharePoint giving me problems.*

I did the following:

- Set up a single Windows Server 2016 machine. We will call it http://win-qbfsb933r5p
- Configured Active Directory Domain Services on this machine and created a new AD forest `win.lab.xxxxxxxxxx.com` and netbios domain `winlab`.
- Create a "kerberos" user in active directory and create a keytab for this user.
- Installed SQL Server 2017.
- Ran SharePoint 2019 prereqs installer.
- Set up a SharePoint single farm server.
- Create a sharepoint web application on port 80.
- Created a single root site collection on this web application at http://win-qbfsb933r5p.
- Open the IIS manager and go to the SharePoint Port 80 web application and go to Authentication modes.

  - Remove `NTLM`.
  - Add `Negotiate`.
  - Disable all other authentication types.
- Run `iisreset`
- Set up FireFox with trusted negotiate auth for http://win-qbfsb933r5p.
- Verify you can access sharepoint with firefox on the server without having to log in.
- Run the powershell `Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://win-qbfsb933r5p -UseDefaultCredentials` and it works.
- Run the mentioned Java example and get a 401 error every time.

Based on these steps, is there some reason I always get HTTP status code 401 Unauthorized from SharePoint when doing requests from Java? Why can I use Java to authenticate fine with other IIS web sites protected by kerberos?

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Here is my DNS Forward Lookup Zones for my server:

[image: DNS forward lookup zones]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing several pieces from what I'm reading. You finish setting up SharePoint to use Kerberos.  I'll try to keep this short.  The original white paper on SharePoint and Kerberos is a 180 pages long.

1. Get your DNS setting for your site and look at your A name.  If your domain is one word, then it's that word.  if it's multiple dots, it's probably just the first one.  e.g.  www.MyCoolSite.com, the DNS A record name is probably www.mycoolsite.com.  Or, if you have something like my.awesome.site.com, then you need to  have my. and my.awesome.site.com
2. Use SetSPN -S http/www.mycoolsite.com DOMAIN\ApplicationPoolAccount
3. add your server names  SetSPN -S http/webservername
4. Delegate the App pool to itself via Active Directory (now that you have SPNs applied, the Delegate tab will be visible)
   A. Click Delegate, Select Any Authentication Protocol, Search for application pool account.  Select everything.  Click OK.  Click Apply

SQL 
Same dealie, except instead of http, you use MSSQLSVC/FQDN-OF-SQL:1433 and MSSQLSVC/NETBIOS-OF-SQL (repeat for each server in a cluster, and repeat for the cluster name)

Central Admin
Set Web Application to use Windows Authentication/Kerberos

IIS
Make sure that both Negotiate and NTLM are present, and that Negotiate is first.
You leave NTLM present as a fallback in case you have DC errors.

The key thing here is that it's not just the user Kerberos ticket you are looking for.  It's the ability of SharePoint (IIS/Windows) to accept that ticket and tell the rest of its services that it's okay to use that ticket.

If your account is logging in okay, you can see it in the Security Event logs under ID 4624 (Detailed Authentication Information, Logon Process, Kerberos)

Edit:  Get your application pool account by going to Central Administration, Security, Configure Service Accounts, Click the drop down and select "Web Application Pool - [IIS Site Name]".  The account that is currently running your web application will be listed under 'Select an account for this component'.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4209.kerberos-survival-guide.aspx

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/kerberos-authentication-planning

Comment: excellent. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Hi @jack. I updated some info to make the ticket more readable. I'm confused about that first step related to the DNS. I pasted a picture of my DNS forward lookup zones. Does this mean I should run `SetSPN -S http/win-qbfsb933r5p winlab\kerberos`?

Comment: Yep, that should be it, assuming that winlab is your domain name and Kerberos is the name of the service account running the SharePoint application pool.  (IIS, to name of SharePoint site, basic settings, application pool name, then IIS, Application Pool, and it should have the service account name shown)

Comment: If "kerberos" is the name of your User that's trying to log in, then it should be more like http/win-qbfsb933r5p winlab\AppPoolServiceAccount

Comment: I had previously been using "Administrator" to run the application pool. I've switched over to using a "poolacct" for running the application pool, and am trying to get the database permission fixed. Currently stuck on `This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2019 Preview Products.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82084/discussion-between-jack-and-nicholas-dipiazza).

Comment: Jack helped me navigate through these instructions but they were definitely spot on. This works now.

Comment: This works now to allow me to download a File from SharePoint. But it will not allow me to make use of soap web services in this manner. 
I am able to do soap web service requests using powershell but not from Java. So is there an extra step needed for soap requests?

Comment: That's a different question, but the hint on that one is that you need to authenticate, establish context, then make your call.  The syntax is slightly different between Java and .NET (Powershell), so make sure you aren't just missing your return.

Comment: yeah that previous question was me being dumb. but now strange thing... my other IIS web application on this server stopped letting my `kerberos` user authenticate to it. It works when I use NTLM to authenticate with `winlab\kerberos`

Comment: SPN has to be added for that application also.  same as before.

Comment: In the discussion i pasted the SPN's for my administrator user. not sure what I'm missing

Comment: "my other IIS web application on this server"  SPNs are set by web application. http/WEBFQDN winlab\[Whatever is running that application]

Comment: does this mean that you must have a single active directory user running app pools? because my mistake was trying to have sharepoint's app pool running under winlab\kerberos, and another IIS web site running under winlab\anotheruser. but then the SPN mapping conflicted so it wouldn't work

Comment: The SPN match is always http\WebFQDN Domain\ApplicationPoolAccount, while it's convenient to use a single SPAppPool service account, it's not a requirement.  You just have to keep an eye on the SPNs + Delegation to make sure they are configured correctly.

Comment: Let's say http\WebFQDN hosts sharepoint on http://WebFQDN:80 and an IIS website on http://WebFQDN:81
do you then require a single application pool account? because `SetSPN -I http\WebFQDN Domain\ApplicationPoolAccount` can only be called for one account

Comment: setspn http/webFQDN Domain\ApplicationPoolAccount  (for 80 and 443)  For non-standard ports, you add the port qualifier.  setspn http/webFQDN:8080 Domain\ApplicationPoolAccount

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It didn't work. without the `http/webFQDN`, http://WebFQDN:81 failed. with it, worked.

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/The-final-Kerberos-guide-0fa27596